# Как изменить размер кнопки?

Tags: android, android-xml

Как сделать более узкую кнопку? С такими параметрами как сейчас она слишком широкая (по вертикали).

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClose"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_close"
            android:onClick="Close"
            android:text="Закрыть"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:typeface="normal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btnClear1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnClear1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnClear1"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".30" />
```

Comment: что вам мешает изменить атрибуты  `android:layout_height` и `android:layout_height`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как у Вас height по содержимому то можно уменьшить размер текста.
Если этот вариант не устраивает, то надо задать параметр  в dp android:layout_height="10dp"

Comment: В dp это же будет фиксированный размер. На экране, сильно отличающемся по размеру, потом может текст не влезть в кнопку?

Comment: Кнока же не может быть меньше текста. А у кнокпи есть стандартный отступ от текста.
Получается, что кнока со стандартными параметрами не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать TextView с background ?attr/selectableItemBackground и задавать padding'и, не мучаясь со стандартными